# Entity Framework native sql mapping to class

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I got a code first EF and I want to use native sql for the more complex select statements. 
When I try to execute:

```
using (VaultsDbContext db = new VaultsDbContext())
{
   var contracts = db.Contracts.SqlQuery("select * from Contracts").ToList<Contract>();
}
```

I got:

> Cannot create a value for property 'MetaProps' of type
>   'DskVault.Models.DbModels.MetaProps'. Only properties of primitive or
>   enumeration types are supported.

`MetaProps` is a class that holds deleteflag, creator etc. and it's a property of all my classes. It's not mapped to a different table, every table has deleteflag, createor, etc.

```
public class Contract
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public MetaProps MetaProps { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to map from the native sql to the class if the class contains a complex type or does EF not support that? Also what if the complex type is entity mapped to another table(join)?

Edit:
Version: Entity Framework 6

Comment: Which version of EF are you using?

Comment: Are you using "code first"? Also, if all your tables have `MetaProps` why don't you create a table for it instead of adding those columns to all the tables that need this. Isn't what the RDB is for?

Comment: @sam I use EF 6. Yes, code first, see first sentence. If I have dedicated table for the metadata then all queries will require join with that table to check for the deleteflag. This lowers the performance and increases the complexity.

Comment: Sorry I missed the code first in the first sentence. I understand your performance concerns however those can be improved by introducing index on different columns that are being joined.
To answer your original question, I don't think you can just map part of a table (Few columns) to a class.

Answer (score 1):

I know from experience not all the fields in your table have to be contained in your model. This is a good thing when it comes to installing updates into production. 
Have you tried reverse engineering your tables on a SEPARATE temporary project using the Entity Framework Power tools? This is a Nuget package that I have found to be extremely useful in code first programming. Reverse engineering will overwrite existing files, so make sure not to do this on your live code.